# NaN on Javascript countdown timer in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, nan

I'm using the following JavaScript for a countdown timer and it has been working great in most browsers, I've just double checked Internet Explorer however and I am getting 'NaN' displayed in place of each number.

Can anyone help to explain where this goes wrong in IE not seeing the individual variables as a number?

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("2018-05-25 12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  if (days.toString().length < 2) {
    days = "0" + days;
  }

  if (hours.toString().length < 2) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if (minutes.toString().length < 2) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds.toString().length < 2) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }


  // Display the result in the element with id="countdown"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + " : " + hours + " : " +
    minutes + " : " + seconds;

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<a href='/register'>Countdown Expired</a>";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: It most likely happens at this point ` var distance = countDownDate - now;` since it's subtracting JS cast Number type on the values and if one of them isn't Number you will get NaN, verify your that countDownDate and now are in fact numbers

Comment: @jerodev is correct. Easiet fix is to initialize with the unix time instead of the string. `var countDownDate = new Date(1527229800000).getTime();` Also using moment will makes things easy for calculating the `diff` between dates.

Comment: @maurycy nope. They are both numbers if the date is a number. However it isn't since IE does not like to parse yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: @mplungjan if IE doesn't like the format what does getTime returns?

Comment: NaN - which means countDownDate.getTime() is NaN before even calculating the difference

Comment: @mplungjan which also means that my comment on checking the type of `countDownDate` is valid since in the subtraction JS cast Number type on `NaN` and it didn't deserved your "nope"

Comment: Yes it did - I does not likely happen where you said it did. And don’t take comments so personally. I’m on my phone. No time to write “Dear Maurycy, I believe you are mistaken when you suspect the statement ....”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just normalise the date and time

```js
function getNormalisedDatetime(dString) { // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
  var parts = dString.split(" ");
  var dParts = parts[0].split("-");
  var tParts = parts[1].split(":");
  return new Date(dParts[0],dParts[1]-1,dParts[2],tParts[0],tParts[1],tParts[2]);
}
function pad(num) {
  return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}

// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = getNormalisedDatetime("2018-05-25 12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  // Display the result in the element with id="countdown"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "" + pad(days) + " : " + pad(hours) + " : " +
    pad(minutes) + " : " + pad(seconds);

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<a href='/register'>Countdown Expired</a>";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works great in all browsers. (Also, thanks for the more elegant solution to the padding - Code was still a little rough and I had forgotten to address this). - All the best!

Answer (score 1):

[MDN discourages the use of a string in the date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) because not all browsers implement this the same way.

If you do want to use date strings, I would recommend using a third party library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to parse these strings to make sure this works in every browser.